# Gray default color textbox but change to black after the user changes the text inside

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `TextBox` in WPF. I want a default value of `999.999.999.999` that would be in gray color.

but when the user change the text will be black.

```
<TextBox x:Name="address_textBox"  
         Height="19" 
         Margin="246,107,166,0" 
         TextWrapping="Wrap" 
         Text="999.999.999.999"  
         VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="128"/>
```

Comment: Are you trying to create placeholder text? or do you want the original value to keep as well?

Comment: I think that's the name "placeholder", The original text is only for demo for the user he should overwrite on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Style` with a `Trigger`?:

```
<TextBox x:Name="address_textBox"  
         TextWrapping="Wrap" 
         Text="999.999.999.999"  
         VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="128">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="999.999.999.999">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

If you want a true watermarked `TextBox`, you could refer to the following article: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20725.wpf-watermarked-textbox-and-passwordbox.aspx. There is a [downloadable sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Watermarked-TextBox-and-444ebdec).